# JSON Policy Shut Down Multiple EC2 Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-policies

I am modifying a json in IAM policy in order to shut down multiple EC2 instances. I am able to shut down one EC2 instance with the following json:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:StartInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:11111111111:instance/i-00000000000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unable to figure out how to shut down multiple instances. I figured I could enter multiple instance IDs but nothing I do seems to be allowed by AWS json policies.

Answer (score 1):

Using tag-based `IAM policies` is a good option here, instead of manually adding instance ids.

There are few other options as well in this doc : [Controlling access during AWS requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_tags.html#access_tags_control-requests)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": ["ec2:StartInstances","ec2:StopInstances"]
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:RequestTag/environment": [
                    "preprod",
                    "production"
                ]
            },
            "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {"aws:TagKeys": "environment"}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So that would mean I have to change my lambda then correct? I have a CloudWatch alarm that triggers my lambda. Goes like this:

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        const ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ region: event.instanceRegion });
        
        ec2.stopInstances({ InstanceIds: [event.instanceId] }).promise()
            .then(() => callback(null, `Successfully stopped ${event.instanceId}`))
            .catch(err => callback(err));
            
};

Comment: @maisonfinder  filtering instances based on tag and allowing operations on them via policy are two different things. So your lambda role must be having the above policy( or somewhat similar based on tags) and  if the event you are getting has the instance ID, then you simply call stop api using the instance ID in the event. I dont see any need to modify the lambda.